# Ruby on Rails - how to deal with gem dependences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, google-cloud-speech

Are there any rules how to solve problems with incompatible gems?

As an example I am showing problem that I currently have after adding `gem 'google-cloud-speech'`

I got error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem
"activesupport":   In Gemfile:
  gcloud_storage was resolved to 0.0.3, which depends on
    gcloud (= 0.7.2) was resolved to 0.7.2, which depends on
      google-api-client (~> 0.8.3) was resolved to 0.8.7, which depends on
        activesupport (< 5.0, >= 3.2)

  jbuilder (~> 2.5) was resolved to 2.7.0, which depends on
    activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

  jbuilder (~> 2.5) was resolved to 2.7.0, which depends on
    activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

  jbuilder (~> 2.5) was resolved to 2.7.0, which depends on
    activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

  rails (~> 5.1.6) was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
    activesupport (= 5.1.6)

  rails (~> 5.1.6) was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
    activesupport (= 5.1.6)

  rails (~> 5.1.6) was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
    activesupport (= 5.1.6)

  rails (~> 5.1.6) was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
    activesupport (= 5.1.6)

  rails (~> 5.1.6) was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
    activesupport (= 5.1.6)

  rails (~> 5.1.6) was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
    activesupport (= 5.1.6)

  rails (~> 5.1.6) was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
    activesupport (= 5.1.6)

  rails (~> 5.1.6) was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
    sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0) was resolved to 3.2.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.0) Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "faraday":   In Gemfile:
  gcloud_storage was resolved to 0.0.3, which depends on
    faraday (= 0.9.0)

  gcloud_storage was resolved to 0.0.3, which depends on
    gcloud (= 0.7.2) was resolved to 0.7.2, which depends on
      grpc (~> 0.13.1) was resolved to 0.13.1, which depends on
        googleauth (~> 0.5.1) was resolved to 0.5.2, which depends on
          faraday (~> 0.12) Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "grpc":   In Gemfile:
  gcloud_storage was resolved to 0.0.3, which depends on
    gcloud (= 0.7.2) was resolved to 0.7.2, which depends on
      grpc (~> 0.13.1)

  google-cloud-speech was resolved to 0.20.0, which depends on
    grpc (~> 1.0)
```

Comment: your gem is not yet ready to be used for rails 5.x since it needs `activesupport (< 5.0, >= 3.2) ` usually something like this is stated on the gems repo (or might not if its not maintained anymore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gem is not yet ready to be used for rails 5.x since it needs activesupport (< 5.0, >= 3.2) usually something like this is stated on the gems repo (or might not if its not maintained anymore)